# Query запрос hibernate ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

Добрый день, есть 2 Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Categories")
public class Category {
@Id
@Expose
private String title;

@Expose(serialize = false)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Ord> orders = new ArrayList<>();

@Expose(serialize = false)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
private List<Provider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
```

и

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Providers")
public class Provider {
@Id
@Expose
private String title;
@Expose
private String phone;
@Expose
private String mobilePhone;
@ManyToMany
@Expose(serialize = false)
@JoinTable(name = "provider_category",
joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "provider",referencedColumnName =    
"title")},
inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category",referencedColumnName = 
"title")})
private List<Category>categories = new ArrayList<>();
```

пытаюсь сделать запрос поставщика с категорией:

```
"FROM Provider as p LEFT JOIN p.categories as c WHERE c.title=:title"
```

не получается...Что не так? Спасибо.

Comment: Попробовал так:                                                                                       {"FROM provider_category pc WHERE pc.category='title'"}  тоже не работает

Comment: А что значит "не получается"? Ошибка, неправильный результат, что именно?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался. Так надо было:

```
 "SELECT p FROM Provider p join p.categories c WHERE c.title=:title"
```